# tomcat war deployment

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm deploying a war file in tomcat name being `"myapps.war"`. I've made an entry in `server.xml` for `docbase` to be `"/callmyapp"`. But after deployment two folders are getting created in the tomcat `webapps` directory -

1. myapps
2. callmyapp

and now I can access my war using two urls one starting with `/myapps` and another `/callmyapp`.
I want only `/callmyapp` as context root to this war and do not want to respond to requests `/myapps`. Any help?

Thanks,
Charu

Answer (score 1):

rename myapps.war to callmyapp.war. tomcat automatically unpacks the war into the directory of same name. Setting a different context then also creates a second directory.

Or you can define a context.xml and put it in your /webapps directory :

```
<Context path="/callmyapp" docBase="webapps/myapps.war" />
```

Comment: I don't want to rename my war, If I was willing to rename my war then why would I need context root at the first place, simply renaming could have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the rename the app.war ? I think the root is inferred from the filename.

Comment: I don't want to rename my war, If I was willing to rename my war then why would I need context root at the first place, simply renaming could have solved the problem.